# How to pass array of dictionaries with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm working on an Android port of an iOS app and I'm having some issues with passing parameters to the API. On the iOS we used Alamofire and the parameter we pass looks like this on the iOS side

```
["topics": [["slug": "health", "importance": 1], ["slug": "environment", "importance": 2], ["slug": "technology", "importance": 0]...]
```

But I can't seem to replicate the same behavior on the Android side using Retrofit 2. I tried creating a Hashmap for each set and then add all of the hash maps to a array list and pass that but it doesn't format correctly when I pass it (like Request{method=POST, url=/api/v1/topics?topics={slug%3Dhealth,%20importance%3D1}&beliefs={slug%3Denvironment,%20importance%3D1}). Here's what I got so far

```
HashMap<String, Object> healthMap = new HashMap<>();
healthMap.put("slug", "health");
healthMap.put("importance", 1);
ArrayList<HashMap> topicList = new ArrayList<>();
topicList.add(healthMap);
...
//Retrofit call
@POST("topics")
Call<String> postBeliefs(@Query("topics") ArrayList<HashMap> topicList);
```